# How to use code highlighting and checking in markdown?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown

In writing markdown files, I may use code blocks with ``` and `. Is there a way I can use code highlighting and checking on just the code blocks inside markdown files?

Comment: what is "checking on just the code blocks"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use default markdown filetype which is bundled with vim (tpope's markdown):

1. make sure you have `let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['dart', 'python', 'ruby', 'go']` in your vimrc. This is the list of vim filetypes to be highlighted in markdown. Of course, your list would be different.
2. in your markdown file use code blocks with filetypes.

Example:

````
```python
def hello():
    print("hello world")
```
````

[image]